# spring data neo4j 2.3.4 - ImpermamentDatabase and version of dependent jars

Tags: spring, neo4j, spring-data-neo4j

Today I wanted to write some tests that use `ImpermamentDatabase`, on Neo4j page: http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/stable/tutorials-java-unit-testing.html it says that `neo4j-kernel` jar must be added with `<type>test-jar</type>` for it to containt test classes.

Now, here is my `build.sbt`:

```
name := """scheduling-backend"""

version := "1.0"

scalaVersion := "2.10.2"

resolvers += "spray repo" at "http://repo.spray.io"

resolvers += "spray nightlies" at "http://nightlies.spray.io"

resolvers += "SpringSource Milestone Repository" at "http://repo.springsource.org/milestone"

resolvers += "Neo4j Cypher DSL Repository" at "http://m2.neo4j.org/content/repositories/releases"

libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  "com.typesafe.akka" %% "akka-actor" % "2.2.0",
  "com.typesafe.akka" %% "akka-slf4j" % "2.2.0",
  "ch.qos.logback" % "logback-classic" % "1.0.13",
  "io.spray" % "spray-can" % "1.2-20130712",
  "io.spray" % "spray-routing" % "1.2-20130712",
  "io.spray" %% "spray-json" % "1.2.3",
  "org.specs2" %% "specs2" % "1.14" % "test",
  "io.spray" % "spray-testkit" % "1.2-20130712" % "test",
  "com.typesafe.akka" %% "akka-testkit" % "2.2.0" % "test",
  "com.novocode" % "junit-interface" % "0.7" % "test->default",
  "org.springframework.scala" % "spring-scala" % "1.0.0.M2",
  "org.springframework.data" % "spring-data-neo4j" % "2.3.4.RELEASE",
  "org.springframework.data" % "spring-data-neo4j-rest" % "2.3.4.RELEASE",
  "javax.validation" % "validation-api" % "1.1.0.Final",
  "com.github.nscala-time" %% "nscala-time" % "0.8.0"
)

scalacOptions ++= Seq(
  "-unchecked",
  "-deprecation",
  "-Xlint",
  "-Ywarn-dead-code",
  "-language:_",
  "-target:jvm-1.7",
  "-encoding", "UTF-8"
)

testOptions += Tests.Argument(TestFrameworks.JUnit, "-v")
```

when looking in `Intellij` I can see that I have for example `neo4j-kernel` dependency in version `1.9.3`, shouldn't it include jars in `2.X` version?

Another question, is it safe for me to just add `neo4j-kernel` with type `test-jar` in newest version or should I add it in the `1.9.3` version (like the existing jar)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have this dependency `org.springframework.data:spring-data-neo4j:2.3.4.RELEASE` which means it will use Neo4j 1.9.3 (including testing).

If you want the latest Neo4j release (2.0 / 2.0.1) then use `org.springframework.data:spring-data-neo4j:3.0.0.RELEASE`.

You must use the same testing version as the normal version. Otherwise you might get tricked into thinking that some things work on the test version (and since it's newer some bugs might be fixed), but in the normal version it will fail.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I switched to `3.0.0` version and added `"org.neo4j" % "neo4j-kernel" % "2.0.1" % "test" classifier "tests"` and everything works fine.